# Setting a PHP timezone - can't update to recent Olson

Tags: php, timezone

*Thanks to recent laws that changed Russian timezone I'm in a heck of trouble with updating time zone for my phpbb forums. Since I'm more of a php programmer than a nix admin, all this is kinda painful for me, so any advice is really appreciated.*

Long story short, executing shell command 'date' returns:

```
Fri Nov 23 11:20:39 MSK 2012
```

which is just fine.

However, in PHP, date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()) returns:

```
2012-11-23 10:20:39
```

which is one hour too early.

PHP date_default_timezone_get() returns:

```
Europe/Moscow
```

I figured that PHP has it's own (outdated) timezone db, so I went ahead and executed:

```
pecl install timezonedb
```

modified php.ini accordingly (adding path to the timezonedb.so), restarted the server and checked

```
php --ri timezonedb
```

It responded just fine

```
Alternative Timezone Database => enabled
Timezone Database Version => 2012.10
```

But the time problem was not fixed at all and when I ask phpinfo() it responds:

```
date
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2010.9
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    Europe/Moscow
```

So command line says timezonedb version is 2012.10, but PHP still uses 2012.9? I don't get this at all =(

Comment: You should check if you have different configuration files for CLI and SAPI. On Debian like machines it's the default.

Comment: Thanks! But looks like this is not the case, as phpinfo() says that 'Loaded Configuration File  /usr/local/lib/php/php.ini' - which is exactly the file I've edited =(

Comment: Solved by a complete server reboot. Thanks though )

Answer (score 0):

Solved by a complete server reboot. Somehow PHP was still running despite restarting nginx multiple times...

Comment: Restarting nginx won't affect php. You have to restart either php fastcgi server (php5-fpm?) or apache with php module. That would certainly help you.

Comment: @deadrunk
Well, looks like you are right, what I really needed to do was something like 'service php-fpm restart'

Comment: Yeah, because nginx is just proxying requests to the backend and has no control over it.